# Add data to Core Data but get nil back

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I use the following method to insert a object into Core Data

```
-(void)createRecordWithTitle:(NSString *)title finishDate:(NSDate *)finishDate limitCount:(int)limitCount {
    [self fetchRecordsIfNecessary] ;
    Record *record = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Record" inManagedObjectContext:self.context] ;
    record.createdDate = [NSDate date] ;
    record.title = title ;
    record.finishDate = finishDate;
    record.limitCount = limitCount ;
    [self.allRecords addObject:record] ;
    [self fetchRecordsIfNecessary] ;
    for (Record *r in self.allRecords) {
        NSLog(@"-->title:%@",r.title) ;
    }
}
```

And using the follow method to get data back from Core Data .

```
-(void) fetchRecordsIfNecessary {
    if (!self.allRecords) {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] ;
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Record" inManagedObjectContext:self.context] ;
        [request setEntity:entity] ;
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdDate" ascending:NO] ;
        [request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor] ] ;

        NSError *error ;
        NSArray *result = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] ;
        // if errors encountered , result is nil , otherwise , it's an valid array
        //context will tack result's changes , and will be saved after you call context's save method
        if (!result) {
            [NSException raise:@"Fetch failed" format:@"%@" , [error localizedDescription]] ;
        }
        self.allRecords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:result] ;
    }
}
```

I set up the NSManagedContext correctly ,add data successfully ,but get all nil data back. Can anyone help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know you are adding the data successfully? Have you stepped through this in the debugger to get an idea of what is actually going on?

Comment: i found out that the context's inserted object is 0 after i adding a object into context ,but when i re-query the context , there's still 
 data in context , but is nil .I don't know why .

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the context!

`[self.context save:&error];`

you need to do the below:

```
-(void)createRecordWithTitle:(NSString *)title finishDate:(NSDate *)finishDate limitCount:(int)limitCount {
    [self fetchRecordsIfNecessary] ;
    Record *record = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Record" inManagedObjectContext:self.context] ;
    record.createdDate = [NSDate date] ;
    record.title = title ;
    record.finishDate = finishDate;
    record.limitCount = limitCount ;
    [self.allRecords addObject:record] ;
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to save - error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    [self fetchRecordsIfNecessary];
}
```

Comment: I didn't save the context in createRecordWithTitle: , but I save the
context after this method.

Comment: i did try to save the context in this method , but didn't work anyway

Comment: Then your are calling `[self fetchRecordsIfNecessary];` before saving the data since you save the context after the method.

Comment: The context doesn't need to be saved in the fetch request is being made to the same context. The save __is__required when fetching from different contexts.

Comment: i did not save the context when fetching , and i use the same context in the app

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by calling NSFetchRequest's  setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO method